# Sort the rows of a data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sorting, dataframe

I have the following data frame (adjusted_RFC_df):

```
     Node               Feature Indicator  Scaled     Class    Direction True_False
0       0                   km        <=   0.181   class_4      0 -> 1         NA
125   125                  gini         =   0.000   class_2    0 -> 126       FALSE
1       1                   WPS        <=   0.074   class_5      1 -> 2        TRUE
52     52                  gini         =   0.000   class_2     1 -> 53       FALSE
105   105                  gini         =   0.492   class_3  102 -> 106       FALSE
102   102           weird_words        <=   0.042   class_4  102 -> 103        TRUE
104   104                  gini         =   0.488   class_4  103 -> 105       FALSE
103   103              funktion        <=   0.290   class_4  103 -> 104        TRUE
107   107                  gini         =   0.000   class_5  106 -> 108       FALSE
106   106           Nb_of_verbs        <=   0.094   class_5  106 -> 107        TRUE
110   110                  gini         =   0.000   class_4  109 -> 111       FALSE
109   109                signal        <=   0.320   class_4  109 -> 110        TRUE
112   112          Flesch_Index        <=   0.627   class_1  112 -> 113        TRUE
115   115                  gini         =   0.000   class_3  112 -> 116       FALSE
114   114                  gini         =   0.000   class_1  113 -> 115       FALSE
113   113       Nb_of_auxiliary        <=   0.714   class_1  113 -> 114        TRUE
..    ...                   ...       ...     ...       ...          ...        ...
```

I am trying to sort the rows based on the value in the 'Direction' column (0 -> 1, means I am trying to sort based on the first number 0). I am trying to do this by using:

```
   ## Sort rows based on first int of Direction column ##
   # create a column['key'] to sort df
   adjusted_RFC_df['key'] = Adjusted_RFC_df['Direction'].apply(lambda    x: x.split()[0])

   # Create new Dataframe with sorted values based on first number of 'Direction' col 
   class_determiner_df = Adjusted_RFC_df.sort_values('key')
```

This works in sorting by the first value before the '->' (the left hand side), however I need the sorting to keep order with the number on the right side of the '->'

So it should look like this:

```
     Node               Feature Indicator  Scaled     Class    Direction True_False
0       0                   km        <=   0.181   class_4      0 -> 1         NA
125   125                  gini         =   0.000   class_2    0 -> 126       FALSE
1       1                   WPS        <=   0.074   class_5      1 -> 2        TRUE
52     52                  gini         =   0.000   class_2     1 -> 53       FALSE
105   105           weird_words         =   0.492   class_3  102 -> 103       FALSE
102   102                  gini        <=   0.042   class_4  102 -> 103        TRUE
104   104              funktion         =   0.488   class_4  103 -> 104       FALSE
103   103                  gini        <=   0.290   class_4  103 -> 105        TRUE
107   107           Nb_of_verbs         =   0.000   class_5  106 -> 107       FALSE
106   106                  gini        <=   0.094   class_5  106 -> 108        TRUE
110   110                signal         =   0.000   class_4  109 -> 110       FALSE
109   109                  gini        <=   0.320   class_4  109 -> 111        TRUE
112   112          Flesch_Index        <=   0.627   class_1  112 -> 113        TRUE
115   115                  gini         =   0.000   class_3  112 -> 116       FALSE
114   114        Nb_of_auxiliary        =   0.000   class_1  113 -> 114       FALSE
113   113                  gini        <=   0.714   class_1  113 -> 115        TRUE
..    ...                   ...       ...     ...       ...          ...        ...
```

It is confusing me as sometimes it does keep the order between the right hand side numbers however most off the time it doesn't.

I thought that maybe it was a problem with sorting strings as the direction col is of type string. So I tried to do the following:

```
adjusted_RFC_df['key'] = adjusted_RFC_df['key'].astype(np.int64)
```

However this causes the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NA'
```

So it seems like it is trying to convert the ['TRUE/FALSE'] column to int as well as just the `['key']` column.

Is it likely a problem with the Direction col being type string?

Or is there a way of sorting based on the first number before the '->' whilst ensuring the the second number is also in order (sorted from smallest to biggest)?

Comment: for `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NA'`, are you sure there are no values of `'NA'` in `adjusted_RFC_df['key']`? Try running `(adjusted_RFC_df['key'] == 'NA').sum()` and make sure it's zero. Or better yet, `adjusted_RFC_df['Direction'].str.contains('NA').sum()`

Comment: and for your problem that sometimes it does keep the order and sometimes it doesn't, it comes from that it sorts based on the key and keeps the same ordering in the initial dataframe between elements that have the same key

Comment: @KenWei, yes it does contain NA, I need to have the last direction as NA as there is no possible value for the last element. Thanks for the tip though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Direction` is always of type string and has also this format `int space '->' space int` like `1 -> 2` then you can get another key to the sorting

```
df['key1'] = df['Direction'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[0])
df['key2'] = df['Direction'].apply(lambda x: x.split()[2])
```

and then sort based on these 2 keys

```
df.sort_values(['key1', 'key2'])
```

edit:
Here is another way to get `key1` and 'key2'

```
df['key1'] = df['Direction'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('->')[0]))
df['key2'] = df['Direction'].apply(lambda x: int(x.split('->')[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks I will try that

Comment: Okay let us know, if it doesn't work it means that Direction column doesn't have always the same format it will need some simple preprocessing before hand

Comment: where does it crash ? at computing key2 ? or at the sorting ?

Comment: At the sorting. It is because I have 'NA' in my direction list, so the format is not identical throughout because of this one element, however I can't really have anything else there to replace it

Comment: or you don't have space because when we try to get key1 and key2 when split the string and get a list of elements (splitted on space) and try to get List[0] and List[2]. If the split actually doesnt have 3 elements it is normal to get a list out of bound. I ll sugfest some preprocessing to you maybe it'll help. Do you need the rows where direction is Nan ?

Comment: Thank you, yes I can see that this should work, once I organised my dataframe a bit better

Comment: Actually, when I view the first hundred or so rows of the dataframe it appears to be working, however when I now look at every single row it turns out that it isn't working. There are still many rows where the second number (on the RHS of '->') is not ordered correctly. I have made sure I now only have all elements with the same format.

Comment: Could you give some examples where it doesn't work ? sometimes just a space can mess things up. I ll see where it doesn't work and give some lines that will preprocess and hopefully work

Comment: edit: I added another way to get key1 and key2, try them out too, if it still doesn't work I ll need examples where it doesn't to understand the problem.